# How to redirect WebFig to HTTPS on Mikrotik

Tags: networking, mikrotik-routeros

I've just enabled SSL for logging in the router administration on my Mikrotik router (IP -> Services -> www-ssl + added new self-signed SSL certificate). I would like the connection on port 80 to my router administration to be redirected to the SSL port 443.

I have tried creating new Firewall NAT rule:

```
ip firewall nat add chain=dstnat dst-address=192.168.1.1 protocol=tcp dst-port=80 action=redirect to-ports=443
```

But it doesn't work. What should I do to make it right?

There is already a dicussion thread on Mïkrotik forum, but with no helpful answers: http://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=101021

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS redirects work by having the HTTP web server sending a HTTP redirect. You cannot accomplish this using a firewall. Even if you made port 80 traffic go to port 443, the result would be equivalent to going to `http://example.org:443/`.

RouterOS does not support this, even today.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `/ip/services/` and disable service `www`

Be sure, that `www-ssl` is enabled and fully configured. After that your NAT rule should work since router is now using port `80` and the traffic to this port can reach NAT chain